# Convert single unicode character to png image

Tags: macos, unicode

I need to convert a Unicode character (e.g. ⦿; CIRCLED BULLET; U+29BF) to a PNG image for use within a reporting tool (Crystal Reports).  I need to preserve the font, size, and formatting of the character.

Is there a more-accurate way to do this than just ⌘⇧+4 and a less-burdensome way than Gimp or Seashore?

Comment: The character viewer does not work for you ? ⦿
CIRCLED BULLET
Unicode: U+29BF, UTF-8: E2 A6 BF

Comment: how large does it appear that ⌘⇧4 isn't accurate enough?

Comment: While I can use the character viewer to select the desired character, pasting the value into a Windows XP application (Crystal Reports) is problematic--the result is a box.

Comment: @TomGewecke: I tried quite a few fonts--didn't work.

Comment: Feel free to self-answer this! The answer shouldn't really be in the question

Comment: @l'L'l: question updated to demonstrate font issue.

Comment: @craig Lucida Sans Unicode does not have the ⌘ character, that is why you get a box.

Comment: Tom is correct, however, [Segoe UI Symbol](http://www.kreativekorp.com/charset/font.php?font=Segoe%20UI%20Symbol) does have both `U+29BF` and `U+2318` on Windows.

Comment: @TomGewecke: How do you know if a font does not contain a certain character (other than the rendering of a box)?

Comment: @craig You can examine the font in Fontbook > Preview > Repertoire or check the Font Variation pane in Character Viewer when the character has been selected.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php):

`convert -pointsize 64 -font /System/Library/Fonts/Apple\ Symbols.ttf label:⦿ output.png`

`convert -background transparent -fill 'hsb(0%,0%,0%)' -font /System/Library/Fonts/Apple\ Symbols.ttf -pointsize 64 -size 200x200 -gravity center label:⦿ output.png`

Comment: Is 200x200 default Emoji resolution or is this just an example of setting the target resolution?

Comment: @MCCCS Original Resolution seams to be 160px, but they're highly detailed and sharp, so you could increase the resolution and it should still look decent.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do it is by typing it in a graphics editor and rasterizing it to a png to whatever size I need. Why not use Gimp or Seashore?

Comment: I need to have the resulting image's dimensions to match the character itself (plus a few pixels buffer).  Honestly, I'm not familiar enough with either tool to know if this is possible.

Comment: Well i mean it's going to be imperfect no mater how you slice it. Youre going from a vector image (made of measurements that dictate the absolute shape and size of the strokes) to discreet pixels in a bitmapped image

Answer (score 1):

Character Map is the (clunky) equivalent of Character Viewer on OS X:

[image: Windoze Character Mope]

Note the Font — only certain typefaces contain `U+29BF` and `U+2318`. Most applications including Crystal Reports support Unicode Fonts.

Comment: How did you know that the Segoe UI Symbol contained this character?  Trial and error?

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution: [Create Banner Image from Text](http://macosxautomation.com/lion/createbanner/index.html)